# SSRS multi-value parameter only returning the last value

Tags: visual-studio, t-sql, reporting-services

I've been having this same issue with various reports over the last month. Before that time, I had no issues with multi-value parameters. I have to be careful what I share here as these are reports I'm developing for my work-place.

Basically, I have over over 28000 records being returned in my query without parameters. I added @ManagingDistrict to my query in the

```
WHERE MNG_DIST_CD IN (@ManagingDistrict)
```

In SSRS, I marked the parameter as "Allow multiple values" and in the Available Values I added 01,02,03,04,05,06,07,99 which are our district numbers.
[image: Parameter Properties window]

In the Dataset Properties window, under Variables tab, I added the join statement.
[image: Dataset properties]

I ran the report and got only 1 district, the last one.
So I tried added the same join statement to my Report Properties>Variables tab:
[image: report properties]

Still I am only getting the last value entered. Here is a screenshot of my Report Preview Tab:
[image]

As you can see, it shows: 01,02,03 but the report is only showing district 03. I've tried adding more districts and it's always the last one in the list. I even tried the

```
MNG_DIST_CD IN (SELECT VALUE FROM STRING_split(@ManagingDistrict , ','))
```

in my query but kept getting error messages that I had too many arguments in my string_split function.

Any suggestions? I've literally read 100 posts on this subject and most I find either involve a udf or the author forgot to use the in clause.

here is my actual where statement from my query:

WHERE CAT_CD IN (1,2) AND SPEC_SQ IN (24,31,68,213) AND SMPL_DT BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate and (@ManagingDistrict = '' OR MNG_DIST_CD IN (@ManagingDistrict));

I originally had this statement and only the Parameter Property of "allow multiple values" set but was getting the error message "expression of non-boolean type......"

Answer (score 0):

If your dataset query is not a stored proc then you do not need to use `JOIN` to pass the values in. SSRS automatically converts your list of values into a comma separated string and injects it into the SQL statement.

There is no need for any variables etc in the dataset query.

Comment: I tried originally with just the "allow multiple values" in parameter properties and the in (@ManagingDistrict) in the query but was getting the error message "An expression of non-Boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected near ','.

Comment: as a test try taking out `@ManagingDistrict = '' OR` .

Comment: I have with no luck. I've taken everything out of my where clause except in(@ManagingDistrict. I either get the error message or I get no results when multiple values are selected. I've also made my query the simplest it can be with no change.

Comment: I don't know why but I took out the available values in the parameter. If you type the values in the preview screen and press enter for each. It works. I assume this has to do with the commas but don't know what or how to do work around do I can have a pick list.

Comment: I created a query for the available values and it works. Still don't know why just a list of available values messed it up. I did notice that by default it showed 01,02,03,04,05,06,07,99,. Don't know if its all the commas or just the last one.

Comment: Ah well that makes sense then. I had assumed you have selected them from a list. For multi-value parameters you can either select from a list (driven from a manual list or from a query) or you can type them in and hit enter between each value, when the dropdown is collapsed it shows then with commas but you do not need to type the commas.

Comment: I'm still confused. Let's say I have created a list manually in available values by clicking the add button and entered 01 02 03 04. When the use checks 01 and 02, what will be sent to the query? 01,02 or 01,02, or 01 02? 

Also, why would creating available values from a query be any different from above?

Everything I see says all I have to do is mark as accepts multi-values and put IN in the where clause. Why suddenly (I've done it that way many times with no problems) is it causing problems?

Comment: I was talking about when you said you "type the values in the preview screen and press enter for each". Adding to the available list manually and getting the list from a database should be essentially the same. Remember that it's the parameter's `Value` that gets passed to the query if you do `IN (@myParameter)` not the label. Also make sure that the parameter datatype is text (even if it is a number). If you selected 1 and 2 the query will be `WHERE myColumn IN(1, 2)`